# Paasing a variable to triggered send email

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, ampscript

I would like to pass a variable to a triggered send email, what is the ampscript function I'd need to use to capture the variable (not a profile attribute) in my email body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Triggered Send Data Extension Template to create your Triggered Send Data Extension. Add the field to your Data Extension, "MyVar". Personalise as though it's an attribute - %%MyVar%%.

If you're firing the triggered send from SOAP or REST, you would pass the variable so...

**SOAP**

```
<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
 <Objects xsi:type="ns2:TriggeredSend" xmlns:ns2="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
    <Client>
        <ID>12345</ID>
    </Client>
    <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
    <TriggeredSendDefinition>
       <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
       <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
       <CustomerKey>MyTriggeredSendCustomerKey</CustomerKey>
    </TriggeredSendDefinition>
    <Subscribers>
       <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
       <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
       <EmailAddress>johndoe@hotmail.com</EmailAddress>
       <SubscriberKey>C1234566</SubscriberKey>
       <Attributes>
          <Name>MyVar</Name>
          <Value>Some value I want to personalise my email with</Value>
       </Attributes>
       <Attributes>
          <Name>MyVar2</Name>
          <Value>Some other value I need in my email</Value>
       </Attributes>
    </Subscribers>
 </Objects>
</CreateRequest>
```

**REST**

```
Host: https://www.exacttargetapis.com
POST /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:MyTriggeredSendCustomerKey/send
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

{
    "From": {
        "Address": "updates@mycompany.com",
        "Name": "MyCompany Inc"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "johndoe@hotmail.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "C1234566",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "MyVar": "Some value I want to personalise my email with",
                "MyVar2": "Some other value I need in my email",
            }
        }
    },
    "OPTIONS": {
        "RequestType": "SYNC"
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to use the personalization strings href="%%MyVar%%" but seeing the following error "The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
Personalization error: %%MyVar%%
 To fix the problem, please try the following:
 - Make sure that there is not a space or typo within the personalization string in your email. For example, check and correct any spaces between percent signs (%%)
 - Correct the HTML Body of your email."
Any idea on how to use the variable?

Comment: Which Data Extension are you doing Send Preview against and does it have a MyVar field?

Comment: hey Sorry, I forgot to change the path, now am able to see the preview. And also I was able to target the triggeredsend DE and start the trigger with no validation errors. Thank you so much, Andrew!